# ASP.net web application label backgrounds will print locally but not when published to IIS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, iis, printing

I have an asp.net (vb) web application that I have created in visual studio 2013 using bootstrap and vb code behind. I am using google chrome to test the application. I have it so the label backgrounds will print the back color and this works perfectly when i debug, but once I publish to IIS server (also running locally on my machine) the label back color will not show up in the print preview. I do have the "Print Background Graphics" option checked.

Am i missing something in the IIS configuration?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked that no files used in the web page are resulting in a 404 error? You can look in Chrome's developer tools or in the relevant IIS log file.

Comment: Ok, so no 404 errors but when when i debug in VS2013 i see the call for bootstrap.css in the developer tools. but when i do the same on my deployed site it is calling bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I renamed bootstrap.min.css in my project and the print preview looks correct now, but i am still seeing call to bootstrap.min.js in chrome developer tools. is that ok? or is there more that i have to do?